# Installing vTigercrm - why URL not found?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vtiger

I am trying to install vTigercrm-5.4.0.tar.gz file via ftp path..
and I am following the following [tutorial](http://www.tmdhosting.com/tutorials/vtiger/vtiger-installation.html)

I uploaded the source file. extracted it to http:///admin

now, when I try to access

```
> http://mydomain.com/admin
```

or

> `http://mydomain/admin/install.php`

I get the following error,

> The requested URL /admin/ was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I googled so much about the issue, but I am at failure in resolving it, vtiger forums is not helping also regarding this issue,, 
Can somebodey tell me why this is happening?

what is possible solution?

Should I have to introduce .httaccess or something else?

I am striking my head for last 10 hours, still at failure, please somebody help me

Comment: That tutorial is referring to an older VTiger version. Why don't you follow the installation guide / manuals here https://www.vtiger.com/crm/help/ ?

Comment: did you give the correct permission to the folder "admin" and to the files?
try to launch the file index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very bad to say and feeling real shame, I was doing a very basic blunder, Damn me...I installed it in `admn` folder and was trying `admin`

can you believe??

sorry, really sorry for this question..I struck my head for oneday long..and when I knew the issue, I was totally mad at myself..let me admit this was the most foolish from me..